# Java: javac command classpath error

Tags: java

I am having some problem with the 'cp' option for javac command. 
As shown in the attached image, I am entering the correct path but it still gives "File not found" error.

I have tried adding ' " " '  (quotation symbol) to the path too, but in vain. I have 2 questions here:

1) What is wrong here?

2) How to put path using '.' (dot) in cmd for 'cp' option?
 Please help

[image: Issue]

EDIT: Going through the oracle site [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), I found this explanation for '-cp option'

-cp path or -classpath path
Specify where to find user class files, and (optionally) annotation processors and source files. This class path overrides the user class path in the CLASSPATH environment variable. If neither CLASSPATH, -cp nor -classpath is specified, the user class path consists of the current directory. See Setting the Class Path for more details.
**If the -sourcepath option is not specified, the user class path is also searched for source files.**

If the -processorpath option is not specified, the class path is also searched for annotation processors.

Comment: The classpath is used for finding classes, not source files. Pass in the name of the source file *relative to the current working directory*.

Comment: Yes, Directly attaching the path to source file worked! Just for information, why doesn't option '-sourcepath' work instead of '-cp', keeping everything else the same? I am giving source path this time right?

Comment: Also I found this here [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)
-cp path or -classpath path:
.
.
.
.
**If the -sourcepath option is not specified, the user class path is also searched for source files.**

Comment: These are searched for source files *referenced by the file you are compiling,* or by such files. Nor for the source file you are compiling. The error message proves it. See [your own link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#searching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) What is wrong here?

The file `Fruit.java` doesn't exist in the folder `c:\user\sony`. That's why `javac` complains. I think you are expecting `javac` to figure out the path to `Fruit.java` from the path specified under the option `cp`. This expectation is incorrect. Javac uses the path specified under the option `cp` or `classpath` to look up for any of your custom classes or annotations that are referenced by `Fruit.java`. If `Fruit.java` doesn't use any custom classes or annotation, you don't need to specify the `cp` option. If it does, you need to make sure you have the `.class` files of those classes referenced by Fruit.java in the folder `c:\user\sony\desktop\java`.

> 2) How to put path using '.' (dot) in cmd for 'cp' option? Please help

In Windows shell, a '.' represents the current working directory. Your usage and expectation is correct. Just do `javac .\desktop\Java\Fruit.java`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. How do I solve this problem though? 
Also please check the added part in question under 'EDIT'.

Comment: @Sirius. (1) To solve your original problem, as stated in the answer, don't use the `-cp` option and make sure that the absolute or relative path to `Fruit.java` is correct. (2) I checked the edited part. What's your question here?

Comment: It says that if the '-sourcepath' is not defined, the user provided classpath is also searched for source files. If this is true then it should find the 'Fruit.java' source file through the '-cp' path I gave, shouldn't it.  Also thanks for help, I'm marking your answer as accepted solution :-)

Comment: @Sirius, no. Source file here means the `.class` files containing the source of your custom java classes and annotations. It won't look at `.java` files.